# For a node app, what's required in the deployment config to connect via cloud proxy?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Trying to connect to a 2nd gen cloud sql database from a GCP Container.

I created the cloud proxy, but am a bit confused on what my app needs to connect via the proxy.  My app is looking to connect on 127.0.0.1:3306 already within the application with all the needed mysql connection information which works fine outside of GCP.  My app is currently logging connection errors against 127.0.0.1:3306 when deployed on GCP container.

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 at Object.exports._errnoException

Any additional sample files available for a simple node app to better understand the needed application config?

The sample below seems to address what wordpress needs, but what do I need for simple node app?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/cloudsql_deployment.yaml

Related Link:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine

Provide 127.0.0.1:3306 as the host address your application uses to access the database.

> I have this hard coded in my app.

Because the proxy runs in a second container in the same pod, it appears to your application as localhost, so you use 127.0.0.1:3306 to connect to it.

> Right, I have this hard coded in my app

Provide the cloudsql-db-credentials secret to enable the application to log in to the database.

> Ok, if I have to add this, what 
>   For example, assuming the application expected DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD:

- name: DB_USER
  valueFrom:
  secretKeyRef:
    name: cloudsql-db-credentials
    key: username
  If your proxy user requires a password, you would also add:

  > So what variable name would I be using here? Is this asking for the mysql user name?
- name: DB_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
  secretKeyRef:
    name: cloudsql-db-credentials
    key: password

  > What variable is needed here? Is this asking for the mysql pw for the id above?

In the wordpress sample from the link above, I'm trying to figure out what variables are needed  for a simple node app.
 containers:
        - image: wordpress:4.4.2-apache
          name: web
          env:
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
              # Connect to the SQL proxy over the local network on a fixed port.
              # Change the [PORT] to the port number used by your database
              # (e.g. 3306).
              value: 127.0.0.1:[PORT]
            # These secrets are required to start the pod.
            # [START cloudsql_secrets]
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: password
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: username
            # [END cloudsql_secrets]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: wordpress

Thanks!